# How to make a v-shaped wave after a jet flying over water

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Im kinda a beginner at blender, and i dont know how to make a v-shaped wave after the jet in the water. I have tried with texture painting, but it seems i have to subdivide the ocean plane, a lot of time, and my computer cant handle that.

[image: Nodes for the ocean plane:]

Comment: When talking about texture Painting, are you referring to Dynamic Paint or Texture paint? Dynamic Paint might be usable for this kind of work where you animate a brush object to get you your animated texture for displacement.